# Why Is My Speed Showing Faster Than Max Speed

Tags: performance, speed, overclocking, resources

I am converting `.mkv` files to `.mp4` files using `handbrake`.  I understand that this program is a total resource hog, but it is the best one I have found that can batch convert.  Regardless of all of that, my system specs show that my `Maximum Speed = 4.00` however when running `handbrake` sometimes my speed spikes to numbers above the maximum (image showing this).

What do I need to do to keep my system from going over maximum speed?  Will my system fail/damage if `handbrake` pushes it to the max and back?

Note -!- I have a factory cooler on this set-up and am not intentionally overclocking my set-up (but from my limited knowledge that is what seems to be taking place).

[System Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bWGj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: This is completely normal. Don't worry.

Long answer: CPU working clock is a complex thing. The company announces a clock speed for it but the CPU rarely ever works as exactly. There are several things that you should consider:

1. The manufacturer has announced a round decimal number as the working clock speed but electrons and atoms of the conductors are far too fuzzy to oblige you with a round decimal number. The actual number is probably close but not always that. This is done for the consumer's convenience: It is inconvenient to tell your friends "my CPU speed is 4,010,000,040 Hz" instead of "4 GHz".
2. CPUs *can* work a good amount above the announced clock speed. See [Overclocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overclocking) on Wikipedia.
3. Windows' calculation of speed is not 100% accurate.

Overall, as long as your CPU temperature is within the accepted range, you needn't worry about its health.

Comment: Those slight variations you talk about would be masked, if not fully eliminated, by the time the OS was given the info.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That's impossible. Imagine the OS calculates a speed of 2,333,445,132. How would it know which part of it (and how much of it) should it mask? And more importantly why would it? And even if it would, how can it (even if it wanted to) account for the APC delay?

Comment: The OS doesn't calculate the CPU speed, that's reported to the OS by the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Your AMD 8350 is 4GHz, with 4.2Ghz "Turbo Boost"/"Turbo Core".

The machine will run at 4Ghz or less, unless you are hammering away on something specifically CPU intensive (like processing video files).  At this point the CPU will shutdown parts if itself it feels you're not using for the task, and uses those resources to bump your clock speed above 4Ghz instead (up to a maximum of 4.2Ghz).

From AMD:

> AMD Turbo Core technology dynamically adjusts to give you a
>   performance boost just when the operating system requests the highest
>   processor performance. If a core is operating below maximum limits and
>   your workload demands additional performance, the processor frequency
>   will dynamically increase until the upper limit of frequency is
>   reached. As your workload subsides, the core returns to normal
>   frequency.

Comment: Are these temps okay?  using CPUID HW Monitor my temps show
CPU        61 - 61 - 61
Mainboard  36 - 36 - 36
FX8350     50 - 49 - 51

Comment: Check the [specs offered by AMD for your CPU](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/cpu#Default=%7B%22k%22%3A%228350%22%7D#2d521741-4cc8-44d2-aa87-874f9bb51787=%7B%22k%22%3A%22%22%7D).

Comment: 61 in Fahrenheit or Celsius? 61° C is the maximum temp. 61 F is absolutely cool.